# Override generic function with a where clause

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overriding

EDITED: Reconstructed the sample code to include a more relevant set of objects.

I have an interesting situation that I'm having trouble finding a solution for.  I have an abstract class with an abstract function that uses generics (see example code below).  In an inheriting class, I'm trying to overload the function, but I'm getting

> Error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Sample.Thingy' to 'T' (CS0030)

Naturally, this isn't my real code, but this code produces the same result as what I'm getting.  If I try casting the return value to (T), I get a similar error.  If I try adding `where T : BaseThingy` or `where T : Thingy`, then I get

> Error CS0460: 'Sample.Container.GetThingy(Guid)': Cannot specify constraints for overrides and explicit interface implementation methods (CS0460)

```
namespace Sample {
    // The abstract base class for thingies
    public abstract class BaseThingy {
        private Guid m_ID;
        private String m_Name;

        public BaseThingy( ) {
            m_ID = Guid.NewGuid( );
        }

        public BaseThingy( Guid id ) {
            m_ID = id;
        }

        public Guid ID {
            get {
                return m_ID;
            }
        }

        public String Name {
            get {
                return m_Name;
            }
            set {
                m_Name = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // The abstract base class for containers
    public abstract class BaseContainer {
        public abstract T GetThingy<T>(Guid id) where T : BaseThingy;
    }

    // Inherits from BaseThingy
    public class RedThingy : BaseThingy {
        private DateTime m_Created;

        public RedThingy( ) : base( ) {
            m_Created = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public RedThingy( Guid id ) : base( id ) {
            m_Created = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public DateTime Created {
            get {
                return m_Created;
            }
        }
    }

    // Inherits from BaseThingy
    public class BlueThingy : BaseThingy {
        public BlueThingy( ) : base( ) {
        }

        public BlueThingy( Guid id ) : base( id ) {
        }
    }

    // Inherits from BaseContainer
    public class Container : BaseContainer {
        private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Guid, RedThingy> m_RedThingies;
        private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Guid, BlueThingy> m_BlueThingies;

        public Container( ) {
            m_Thingies = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Guid, BaseThingy>();
        }

        public override T GetThingy<T>( Guid id ) where T : BaseThingy {
            if( typeof( T ) == typeof( RedThingy ) {
                if( m_RedThingies.ContainsKey( id ) ) {
                    return m_RedThingies[ id ];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else if( typeof( T ) == typeof( BlueThingy ) ) {
                if( m_BlueThingies.ContainsKey( id ) ) {
                    return m_BlueThingies[ id ];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void AddThing( RedThingy item ) {
            if( item != null && !m_RedThingies.ContainsKey( item.ID ) ) {
                m_RedThingies.Add( item.ID, item );
            }
        }

        public void AddThing( BlueThingy item ) {
            if( item != null && !m_BlueThingies.ContainsKey( item.ID ) ) {
                m_BlueThingies.Add( item.ID, item );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, after reading through the answers, I believe I have a solution.  I was thinking this was a compiler limitation, but I guess it has more to do with too much code and not enough caffeine input.  Thanks all (Eve, especially) for your input.

My solution is to change this:
`public abstract T GetThingy<T>( Guid id );`
to this:
`public BaseThingy GetThingy<T>( Guid id );`

Thanks again, everyone!

Comment: It depends on what you need from that method. If you are ok with just BaseThingy, good!

Comment: Originally, I wanted the return type to match the generic type T, but there is a compiler limitation that prevents that from happening using the design pattern I have.  If you have an alternative suggestion that doesn't involve a major overhaul of the design pattern, I may consider it.  My actual project is composed of 4 projects containing over 100,000 lines of code in just over 120 classes, most of which inherit from one of three base class types.

Comment: But there's no compiler limitation. The language provides a way of doing what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: Please elaborate.  The signature `public abstract T GetThingy<T>( Guid id ) where T : BaseThingy;` seems the most intuitive to me, but the compiler doesn't seem to like it when I return any types that inherit from BaseThingy.  And trying to specify the same constraint on the overridden method throws a different exception.  What am I missing?

Comment: There is a very specific problem with this design pattern.  You can verify this against what Eve has been saying, but if you pass `ThingyType1` into the method, but there's a line that returns a `ThingyType2`, the error is thrown because a `ThingyType2` cannot be converted to a `ThingyType1`.

Comment: You have to cast it to T.

Comment: That doesn't work unless you explicitly overload the cast operator in every class that inherits from `BaseThingy` for every other class that inherits from `BaseThingy`.  And since there might be other classes down the line that inherit, I can't feasibly do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the type you pass has to inherit from `BaseThingy` but it doesn't imply that you can cast a `Thingy` to it. Let me make an example to simplify it:

```
abstract class BaseThingy
{
}

class Thingy1 : BaseThingy
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

class Thingy2 : BaseThingy
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
    }
}

class Foo
{
    static T GetItem<T>() where T : BaseThingy
    {
        //Won't compile, Thingy1, while deriving from BaseThingy
        //Could not be the same type of T, derive from it or have
        //An implicit cast operator to T.
        return new Thingy1();
    }

    static void Bar()
    {
        var result = GetItem<Thingy2>();
        //But your method is returning a Thingy1,
        //which doesn't have the following method
        result.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

`Bar()` will expect `result` to be of type `Thingy2` but `GetItem` is trying to return a `Thingy1`.

Comment: In my original code, I have one base class, which is inherited by 3 other classes.  Each of those three class are inherited by numerous other classes.  I also have a "container" base that contains a definition of `public abstract T LoadItem<T>(...) where T : BaseItem` (which is overridden in other "container" classes.

Comment: Let's throw another class into my original example.  Say there are 4 different `Thingy` classes, each inheriting from `BaseThingy`.  The `GetThingy<T>` function would return the `Thingy` object that matches the type specified by `T`.  If I'm returning the super class, as long as it inherits from the base class, why does this throw an exception?

Comment: @JasonSatterfield I don't understand what your comment implies. My answer states that you pass the expected return type to your method and in its body you're trying to return a type which doesn't necessarily derive or can be implicitly cast to your type.

Comment: @JasonSatterfield I've edited my example, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Actually, the type that gets returned does derive from the type that gets passed into the function. The `BaseContainer` class specifies that the type MUST derive from `BaseThingy` by using the "where T : BaseThingy` clause at the end of the function signature.  I can't specify another `where` clause, because it's an overridden function.  I also can't return a type that does derive from `BaseThingy` because it says I can't convert `RedThingy` to type `T` (even though T inherits from `BaseThingy`, and `RedThingy` inherits from `BaseThingy`).

Comment: @JasonSatterfield That is not the point. By putting `T` as the method's return type you're explicitly telling the compiler that the type passed to the method is also going to be the same one to be returned. What you said would apply if the method's return type was `BaseThingy`, not `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as you already set the constraints in the base class you don't need to specify them again in the derived classes. That's why it gives that error.

Besides it produces this error, I don't get what is the problem you have. Just don't specify the constraints in the inherited classes.

In order to solve the conversion problem, you have to cast it:

```
public T Get<T>() where T : Thingy
{
    RedThingy thingy = GetRedThingy();
    return (T)thingy;
}
```

In case the compiler doesn't let you do that (I don't have Visual Studio open now) you can cast it first to object and then to T (This is a workaround that does the job).

```
public T Get<T>() where T : Thingy
{
    RedThingy thingy = GetRedThingy();
    return (T)((object)thingy);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you have to specify them in the base.  I'm pretty sure it will tell you that it inherits the constraints from the base class whether you specified them there or not.

Comment: Exactly. Just in the base and nowhere else.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant now; I thought you were suggesting he specify them in the derived class instead of in the base class.  Of course, that still leaves the problem he's having which is that he designed his solution on the assumption that he could cast the result to a more derived implementation than the constraint calls for.

Comment: +1 This provides a correct solution while maintaining the strong-typing for the return value.

Comment: This won't compile because of the abstract nature of my original function signature.  You can't specify the `where T : BaseThingy` on an overridden function.  You also can't cast (explicitly or otherwise) two classes that both inherit from a common base class without overloading the cast operators.  Unfortunately, because I don't know what the next programming might use the `BaseThingy` class for, I can't do that.  I've attempted this approach already, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You define the constraint the abstract method, not in the overridden method. And then you cast it to what you want to return. The only case where it won't make sense is if you actually are not returning a T but another type. In that case, the design of your API was wrong.

Comment: This seems to be the most common answer (and one I would love to have work), but it simply won't work because you can't cast a derivative type of `BaseThingy` into another derivative type of `BaseThingy` without explicitly defining `public static operator {X}Thingy ({Y}Thingy it);` for every iteration of {X} in every class of {Y} (where {X} is every type of derivative class of `BaseThingy` and {Y} is the containing derivative class of `BaseThingy`).

Comment: Ok, that means you the API was wrong, because you didn't wanted to return T. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix would be to change your base implementation constraint to be a Thingy instead of a BaseThingy.  If that doesn't make sense for your application, then it's highly likely that you're just not using the best design pattern to solve your problem.  In the latter case, if could explain a little more about your problem at a high level then I'm sure we could give you some other suggestions on how to approach it.

Comment: And by 'highly likely' I mean definitely ;)